# CSS Zoom does not work - iPad OS (v13 - latest) Safari

Tags: css, ipad, safari, zooming

I have discovered a bug in Safari with iPad OS. The problem is that when I zoom using the css zoom attribute, safari is taking an element's font-size and is either enlarging or shrinking based on the zoom level.

Example: If I have an element with font-size: 20px at 100% and zoom to 50%, safari is making the font-size now 40px keeping the element at 100% therefore breaking my layout. This only occurs only on devices running iPad OS. (This happens at all zoom levels 50%, 60%, 70%, etc.)

Does anyone have any extra information on iPad OS that may help me solve this problem? I have already reported to Apple, but it has been a while since I have had any status update.

LINK TO TEST: http://alleetest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: can you re-check the issue in the latest version? Does it still exist?

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).

Answer (score 3):

You can set a CSS property to disable this anti-zoom effect, [`-webkit-text-size-adjust: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust). Chrome/Edge browsers support `text-size-adjust` unprefixed, but Safari supports it with a `-webkit` prefix.

This "feature" was introduced in iPadOS 13 as part of Apple's "[Desktop-class Browsing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/203/)" initiative. Desktop-class Browsing is mostly a bunch of "[interventions](https://github.com/WICG/interventions)."

> An **intervention** is when a user agent [a browser] decides to deviate slightly from a standardized behavior in order to provide a greatly enhanced user experience. Because of its nature, it must be done sparingly and with extreme prudence.

In this case, iPadOS Safari 13+ intervenes against the CSS [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) property. `zoom` is non-standard, but it's been supported on most browsers for many years, including Safari. The result IMO is "semi-standardized," but browser vendors feel a bit freer to intervene on CSS properties that aren't formally standardized.

Safari's `zoom` intervention is to automatically divide the `font-size` by the `zoom` factor.

For example, if `zoom` is set to `2` and your `font-size` is `16px`, everything (including fonts) would normally appear double size, but Safari will divide `font-size` by 2, setting it to `8px`. When `zoom` doubles everything, it will undo the effect of the division, so the text will appear un`zoom`ed.

On the other hand, if `zoom` were set to `0.5`, that would divide by 0.5, i.e. multiply by 2, setting `font-size` to `32px`. Again, when the zoom kicks in, the text will appear un`zoom`ed.

You can see this effect by viewing the snippet below in iPadOS Safari 13+. The first section will appear unzoomed; the second section will be properly zoomed. If you use Safari Dev Tools to inspect the "unzoomed" elements, you'll see that their `font-size`s have been divided to counteract the effect of the zoom!

```css
body {
    display: flex;
}

section.fixed div {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name='viewport' content='width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
          <h1>-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;</h1>
          <div style="zoom: 1">zoom 1</div>
          <div style="zoom: 2">zoom 2</div>
          <div style="zoom: 3">zoom 3</div>
          <div style="zoom: 4">zoom 4</div>
          <div style="zoom: 5">zoom 5</div>
          <div style="zoom: 0.5">zoom 0.5</div>
        </section>
        <section class="fixed">
          <h1>-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;</h1>
          <div style="zoom: 1">zoom 1</div>
          <div style="zoom: 2">zoom 2</div>
          <div style="zoom: 3">zoom 3</div>
          <div style="zoom: 4">zoom 4</div>
          <div style="zoom: 5">zoom 5</div>
          <div style="zoom: 0.5">zoom 0.5</div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are also ways to disable Safari's Desktop-class Browsing interventions altogether. If you're embedding a WKWebView in an iPad app, you can set  [`WKWebpagePreferences.ContentMode = mobile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebpagepreferences/3194426-preferredcontentmode) to disable Desktop-class Browsing.

Users can also manually disable Desktop-class Browsing by clicking the <kbd>Aa</kbd> button in the URL bar, and selecting "Request Mobile Website."

Answer (score 1):

IMPORTANT,

For anyone following or coming across this issue, I have discovered a bug with Safari. The problem is Apple is not correctly scaling text when the page is magnifyied when using the css zoom attribute. For example, if I have an element with font-size: 20px and set the zoom to 50% instead of scaling to 10px Apple is actually setting the font-size to 40px and so on for 60%, 70%...

Safari is only having this problem on iPad OS 13 and newer. To simply see this just console.log() the font-size of whatever element after each zoom change and you can see the font actually change from 20px to 40px.

**New and Better Solution:**

```
function setTransformScale(scaleFactor) {
    if(!scaleFactor) scaleFactor = 1;

    let height = $(window).height()*(1/scaleFactor);
    let width = $(window).width()*(1/scaleFactor);

    $(".body-container").css({
        width: width+"px",
        height: height+"px",
        transform: `scale(${scaleFactor})`
    });
};
```

I have completely removed the CSS Zoom property from my site and switched to transform: scale() property. To counter the spacing I added "transform-origin: top left" to my css file and in javascript I run my created function when sizing pages.

$(".body-container") is my div element right below the body tag causing the zoom effect on my entire page.

Old SOLUTION:

```
function updateText({page, scale}){
    if($(page).length > 0) {
        console.log(scale);
        $(page).css("font-size", "");
        let fontSize = parseInt($(page).css("font-size"), 10) * (scale * scale);
        $(page).css("font-size", fontSize+"px");
        for (let i = 0; i < $(page).children().length; i++) {
            const branch = $(page).children()[i];
            updateText({page: branch, scale});
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably not the most efficent solution, but whatever the scale is I do scale * scale then multiply that to the font that needs to be adjusted! I hope this is fixed soon!